# *Solved* Terminology in DE, difference between Particular and Actual solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

Yesterday I started studying and preparing for a course in *Differential Equations* and today I came across something that confuses me; I watched a lecture on IVP and they used both *Actual solution* and *Particular solution*, as you can see here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6WMmmMKf3Y so could someone please explain the difference? Is it something simple like *Slope fields* and *Direction fields*, where the only difference is the direction in *Direction fields*? I googled this and that, but with no luck. As I understand it, particular solution is a specific solution, opposite of a general solution, like when we have a slope field.

Comment: From the slides only I can say that "actual solution" and "particular solution" are just two interchangeable terms.

Comment: You're right, the course started and now that I asked him, he said he never heard of *Actual solution* before, but from what he could tell (from the video, that is) that they seem to be interchangeable, at least in these slides.